# Linq custom query with object properties

Tags: c#, linq

I want know to make a query using linq, between a collection of objects
and a collection of values. In the sample code below, I make the question about it.

```
class USER
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        List<USER> listUser = new List<USER>();
        listUser.Add(new USER { Name = "A" });
        listUser.Add(new USER { Name = "B" });
        listUser.Add(new USER { Name = "C" });
        listUser.Add(new USER { Name = "D" });

        string[] arrayNames = { "A", "B" };
    }
}
```

Using Linq how can I get all `USER` in `listUser` with them Name equals to the `arrayNames` values.?

The expected results wold be

```
        //listUser[0] --> User with Name == "A"
        //listUser[1] --> User with Name == "B"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HashSet<string> names = new HashSet<string>(new string[]{ "A", "B" });
var selectedUsers = listUser.Where(user => names.Contains(user.Name));
```

The hashset is optional and overkill if you have only a few users but it guarantees optimal lookup performance if you have a lot of users.

Answer (score 0):

```
listUser.Where(u => arrayNames.Contains(u.Name)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should so what you want, tried it in a console app. Worked a treat

```
var query = listUser.Where(i => arrayNames.Contains(i.Name));

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

The key part is the `arrayNames.Contains(i.Name)` as this is inverse to intuition in that you specify the IEnumerable and then the linq parameter inside the contains method.

Answer (score 0):

```
listUser = (from u in listUser where arrayNames.Contains(u.Name) select u).ToList();
```